# InvalidCastException: ConstantExpression to LambdaExpression in MongoDB Driver

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb, lambda, mongodb-.net-driver

How can I wrap this into a reusable expression that I can use elsewhere in my code?

```
nv => nv.a == nv2.a
```

I've tried doing this, but seems to return a `ConstantExpression` rather than a `LambdaExpression`.

```
public Func<EntityName, bool> compareExpression()
{
    return nv => nv.a == this.a;
}
```

I don't mind exactly how I do this, as long as I can have a LambdaExpression that I can use in more than one place in the code. The DB driver will be reading the expression and converting it.

**More Detail**

Given this;

```
db.p.insert(
  {
    arrayNest: [
      { a:1, b:10 },
      { a:2, b:20 },
      { a:3, b:30 },
      { a:4, b:40 },
]
  }
);
```

and

```
class NV {
    int a;
    int b;
    public Func<EntityName, bool> compareExpression()
    {
        return nv => nv.a == this.a;
    }
}
class P {
     NV[] arrayNest;
}
```

And a methods;

```
    public virtual void Delete(Expression<Func<T, bool>> criteria)
    {
        this.Collection.Remove(Query<T>.Where(criteria));
    }

    var nv2 = new NV();
    Delete(p => p.arrayNest.Any(nv => nv.a == nv2.a)); // Works fine
```

However, when I use the lambda from function that returns an expression;

```
    Delete(p => p.arrayNest.Any(nv => nv2.compareExpression())); // FAILS
```

I get a

```
 System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'.

 Result StackTrace: 
  at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.PredicateTranslator.BuildAnyQuery(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
```

I see that `MongoDB.Driver.Linq.PredicateTranslator` assumes that every expression is a `(LambdaExpression)`.

So is this a driver issue, or am I doing something else wrong? 
What's wierd is I don't understand why it's evaluating to a ConstantExpression at all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `compareExpression` method returns an expression rather than the boolean that the `Any` method is looking for.  You can invoke the expression returned by `compareExpression` like this:

```
Delete(p => p.arrayNest.Any(nv => nv.compareExpression().Invoke(nv)));
```

but the way you have `compareExpression` written the object passed into `compareExpression` is the same as the `this` object, so it will always return true.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I think I can almost see now why I'm getting a `ConstantExpression`, but I thought Any() was expecting a `Func<>`. I don't *want* it to calculate the bool in any case. I need the expression so that the DB driver can process it and convert it to a server side query.

Comment: Any does take a `Func<>`, but that `Func<>` has to return a boolean.  In your working example `nv.a == nv2.a` returns a bool, but in the non-working code, `nv.compareExpression()` returns another `Func<>`.

Comment: Yes, I want a Func<> not a bool. Or at least I thought I did. Have a look at the top, I've re-worded the start of my question. I think my problem has something to do with the way Expression trees are evaluated. I don't EVER want Any() to execute, I only want the expression tree so that the DB layer can translate.

Comment: Actually, regarding the "this" reference, I just noticed a typo (now updated and corrected) where I was calling nv.compareExpression(). It should have been nv2.compareExpression(). It's a typo on SO though, the code was doing it right, but I was still getting the ConstantExpression error.

Comment: You can reuse the expression by declaring it like `Func<NV, bool> exp = nv => nv.a == nv2.a;`, then using such as `Delete(p => p.arrayNest.Any(exp));`  You can then pass `exp` around as needed.

Comment: Sure, that creates a closure around nv2, but it's the algorithm I want to capture where nv and nv2 are parameters (hence my this pointer attempt), and I need to get it as a Func<> LamdaExpression. I've done this before with Expression<Func<NV,bool>> which works ok, but Any() in this case wants an inline Lambda, not an Expression. I've tried the Body property, but I end up back at the ConstantExpression problem.